# how to trigger rules when a new item is added to a view?

Tags: rules, views

I would like to trigger a rules action when my proximity map returns new listed nodes. I can include a VBO for the proximity map, and set a rules action for 'VBO returns a list" with 1 or more items. But how can I specify it to be triggered by an event or condition that the view returns a new item? (Ie when a users location brings a new node in proximity?).

Comment: The problem is - item is *never* "added to view". That's simply not how it works. what really happens is that 1) Item is added to *site*. Or edited and saved - on *site* Period. 2) View is displayed and grabs some items. now when you know what happens and what does not, please rethink your issue :)